# Google Play Game Services Open Page Programmatically

Tags: android

NOTE: I dont want to open the app on the Google Play Store!, this is the app page in the Game Play Services I want!

If i start up the 'Play Games' icon on the android and goto My Games, i can click on my app to get to the page about it. Is it possible to programatically go here when a user clicks a button in my app?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to link to the html page

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mypackagename

when the user presses a button on your app.

Yes, you can do this, for example by using a webview.